# VueJs v-for with filter checkbox becomes checked on next item

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Please run code snipped to see problem replicated.**

I have a boolAutoFilter function with following logic:

if filter is null all items pass test

if filter is true/false item passes if prop is equal to filter val

the problem is... when bool filter is set to false, and user clicks checkbox to change value of property from false to true, that item disappears and the checkbox of the next item becomes checked even through the prop val remains false.

```js
function boolAutoFilter(item, boolFilters) {
    var returnVal = true;
    for (var prop in boolFilters) {
        if (!item.hasOwnProperty(prop) || boolFilters[prop] === null)
            continue;
        returnVal = returnVal && ((item[prop] || false) === boolFilters[prop]);
    }
    return returnVal;
};
window.onload = function () {
    window.app = new Vue(
        {
            el: '#app',
            data: {
              filters: {
                  boolFilters: {
                      active: false,
                  },
                  stringFilters: {},
              },
              items: [
                { id: 1, active: false },
                { id: 2, active: false },
                { id: 3, active: false },
                { id: 4, active: false },
                { id: 5, active: false },
                { id: 6, active: false },
                { id: 7, active: false },
                { id: 8, active: false }
              ]
            },
            methods:{
                mainItemFilter: function (item) {
                    const boolFilters = this.filters.boolFilters;
                    var rVal = true;
                    rVal = rVal && boolAutoFilter(item, boolFilters);


                    return rVal;
                }
            },
            computed: {
                filteredItems() {
                    var vm = this;

                    return this.items.filter(function (item) {
                        return vm.mainItemFilter(item);
                    });
                }
            }
        })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in filteredItems">
        <td>
          {{item.id}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.active" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  {{items}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a unique `key` property to all the elements you loop over in the ``v-for`, or Vue will try to reuse the same instance of the component over again so any state changes that happens to one instance will be reflected in all the other instances.

Try changing your loop to something like `<tr v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems" v-bind:key="item + "_" + index" />`

(Use template literals instead of `item + "_" + index`), its just because markdown uses the same symbols I couldn't show whilst writing code block.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are having issues because you are using the "active" property for filtering items and the checked state.

I added "checked" property to the objects in items array and updated the html to use item.checked instead of item.active and the checkboxes no longer disappear.

```
function boolAutoFilter(item, boolFilters) {
    var returnVal = true;
    for (var prop in boolFilters) {
        if (!item.hasOwnProperty(prop) || boolFilters[prop] === null)
            continue;
        returnVal = returnVal && ((item[prop] || false) === boolFilters[prop]);
    }
    return returnVal;
};
window.onload = function () {
    window.app = new Vue(
        {
            el: '#app',
            data: {
              filters: {
                  boolFilters: {
                      active: false,
                  },
                  stringFilters: {},
              },
              items: [
                //updated with checked
                { id: 1, active: false, checked: false },
                { id: 2, active: false, checked: false },
                { id: 3, active: false, checked: false },
                { id: 4, active: false, checked: false },
                { id: 5, active: false, checked: false },
                { id: 6, active: false, checked: false },
                { id: 7, active: false, checked: false },
                { id: 8, active: false, checked: false }
              ]
            },
            methods:{
                mainItemFilter: function (item) {
                    const boolFilters = this.filters.boolFilters;
                    var rVal = true;
                    rVal = rVal && boolAutoFilter(item, boolFilters);


                    return rVal;
                }
            },
            computed: {
                filteredItems() {
                    var vm = this;

                    return this.items.filter(function (item) {
                        return vm.mainItemFilter(item);
                    });
                }
            }
        })
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in filteredItems">
        <td>
          {{item.id}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <!-- updated with checked -->
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.checked" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  {{items}}
</div>
```

Hope this helps you get on the right track.

Comment: I need to be able to change the active property and filter based on it. so this doesn't help

Comment: Well this should explain why your items are disappearing. Hope this helps you get on the right track.

Comment: The items are disappearing as expected. The problem is that the next item checkbox becomes checked even through the active prop val is false.